# Благодаря этому

Tags: пунктуация

Обособляется ли оборот **"Благодаря этому"**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**БЛАГОДАРЯ** ― это производный предлог на основе деепричастия, обособление оборотов с производными предлогами факультативно (зависит от позиции оборота и его распространенности).

Падежная форма **БЛАГОДАРЯ ЭТОМУ**  является нераспространенной и  обычно не обособляется, но может обособляться в удобной для этого позиции:

а)  **Благодаря этому** во мне выработалась самостоятельность и внутренняя свобода. [Н. А. Бердяев. Автобиография (1917)]. **Благодаря этому** российская компания сможет выйти на рынки Западной Европы, Африки, Азии. [Алексей Грамматчиков, 2014].

б) В XIV веке, **благодаря этому**, Византия и её императоры продолжали претендовать на номинальное Вселенское владычество. [Иоанн Мейендорф. (1992)]. И конечно, вопрос «о Боге» делался, **благодаря этому**, совсем новым, розановским. [З. Н. Гиппиус (1923)].

**Примечание**. БЛАГОДАРЯ ТОМУ, ЧТО ― это союз, обычно расчлененный.

Answer (score 0):

> [БЛАГОДАРЯ ТОМУ, ЧТО,](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_57) союз
>   Придаточные предложения, присоединяемые союзом «благодаря тому, что», выделяются (или отделяются) запятыми. При этом первая запятая обычно ставится не перед союзом, а между его частями (перед словом «что»).
>   Старинное башкирское название этих гор как-то потерялось, а нынешнее они получили благодаря тому, что по увалам и россыпям росла в особенном изобилии малина. Д. Мамин-Сибиряк, Малиновые горы. Если Англия может указать в военной истории на самые блестящие кавалерийские дела, то только благодаря тому, что она исторически развивала в себе эту силу животных и людей. Л. Толстой, Анна Каренина. Благодаря тому, что лето было очень жаркое и сухое, понадобилось поливать каждое дерево, на что ушло много времени и рабочей силы... А. Чехов, Черный монах. Зубовых удалось вернуть благодаря тому, что заинтересовали в этом деле Кутайсова, неизменного Павлова любимца. О. Форш, Михайловский замок.

[«Благодаря этому», «благодаря тому», «благодаря тому-то» и «наряду с тем-то» — запятая, как правило, не требуется. Обособление факультативно. Наличие запятой ошибкой не является.](http://baddcat.livejournal.com/92274.html)